# How to print all nodes in Binary Search Tree only use iostream library?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I'd like to print all nodes in tree(nodes with low levels are printed first, for nodes with the same output level, the node has a small value are printed first)
For example: **Input**
[image]

**Expected output: 10 6 20 1 8 18 21 7 25.**
I tried to code like this

```
void print_Nodes(Node *root)
{
    if(root == nullptr) return;
        cout << root->value << " ";
    if(root->left!=nullptr){
        cout << root->left->value << " ";
        if(root->right!=nullptr){
            cout << root->right->value << " ";
        }
    }
    print_Nodes(root->right);
    print_Nodes(root->left);
}
```

But the output was : **10 6 20 6 1 8 1 8 7 7 20 18 21 18 21 25.**
Could you guide me how to fix this?

Comment: This question could have been rendered unnecessary with a tiny bit of debugging.

Comment: @user4581301 could you pls explain me more?

Comment: what the commenter meant is that you could have used a debugger to step through your code to see what each line does. Though, you don't even need to use a debugger, the result of each line readily appears on your screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are printing `root->left->value` and then call `print_Nodes(root->left)` which again prints `root->value` (where `root` is the previous `root->left`). Thats why they all appear twice.

Moreover you are doing a Depth First traversal while you actually want a Breadth First traversal. To traverse all nodes on one level before you continue to the next you need an additional data structure to remember nodes such that you can later come back to them and continue downwards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
struct Node {
    Node* left = nullptr;
    Node* right = nullptr;
    Node(int value) : value(value) {}
    int value;
};

void bft(Node* root) {
    std::queue<Node*> q;
    q.push(root);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        Node* current = q.front();
        q.pop();
        std::cout << current->value << " ";
        if (current->left) q.push(current->left);
        if (current->right) q.push(current->right);    
    }
}

int main() {
    Node root(10);
    Node n6(6);
    Node n20(20);
    Node n1(1);
    Node n8(8);
    Node n18(18);
    Node n21(21);
    Node n7(7);
    Node n25(25);

    root.left = &n6;
    root.right = &n20;
    n6.left = &n1;
    n6.right = &n8;
    n20.left = &n18;
    n20.right = &n21;
    n8.left = &n7;
    n21.right = &n25;

    bft(&root);
}
```

Comment: but ya know, I want the nodes in low level are printed first. Your code is printing **Postorder** and your output is ** 10 20 21 25 18 6 8 7 1 **. But my expected output is **10 6 20 1 8 18 21 7 25**

Comment: @idclev463035818: His intended result is Breadth First, which requires a separate stack data structure that you push and pop nodes off of. His code and your code are both Depth First, which uses recursive calls and no data structure. https://www.educative.io/edpresso/dfs-vs-bfs#:~:text=BFS%20starts%20traversal%20from%20the,using%20a%20queue%20data%20structure.

Comment: @MooingDuck oh. Thanks for explanation. I'll read the link and maybe update the answer. Eventually I do learn something about writing trees :P